# Oozie variable[user] cannot ber resolved

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

I'm trying to use Oozie's Hive action in Hue. My Hive script is very simple:

`create table test.test_2 as
select * from test.test`

This Oozie action has only 3 steps:

1. start
2. hive_query
3. end

My job.properties:

```
jobTracker  worker-1:8032
mapreduce.job.user.name     hue
nameNode    hdfs://batchlayer
oozie.use.system.libpath    true
oozie.wf.application.path   hdfs://batchlayer/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_hue_-oozie-4-1425575226.04
user.name   hue
```

I add hive-site.xml two times - as file and as job.xml. Oozie action starts and on second step stops. Job is 'accepted'. But in hue console I've got an error:

```
variable[user] cannot ber resolved
```

I'm using Apache Oozie 4.2, Apache Hive 0.14 and Hue 3.7 (from Github).

**UPDATE:**

This is my workflow.xml:

```
bash-4.1$ bin/hdfs dfs -cat /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/*.04/work*

<workflow-app name="ccc" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="ccc"/>
    <action name="ccc">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <job-xml>/user/hue/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
            <script>/user/hue/hive_test.hql</script>
            <file>/user/hue/hive-site.xml#hive-site.xml</file>
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: In the generated XML, do you see any 'user' variable?

Comment: No, I don't have any variables,

Comment: "variable [user] cannot be resolved"

 is could be a misleading error message. For us, by restarting the workflow everything went fine. There were a related jira ticket (OOZIE-1580) but fixed in version 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Tried running a sample hive action in Oozie following similar steps as you, and was able to resolve error faced by you using following steps

1. Remove the  add for hive-site.xml
2. Add following line to your
       job.properties oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib
3. Increase visibility of your hive-site.xml file kept in HDFS. Maybe
       you have very restrictive privileges over it (in my case 500)

With this both the [user] variable cannot be resolved and subsequent errors got resolved.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This message can be really misleading. You should check yarn logs and diagnostics.

In my case it was configuration settings regarding reduce task and container memory. By some error container memory limit was lower than single reduce task memory limit. After looking into yarn application logs I saw the true cause in 'diagnostics' section, which was:

`REDUCE capability required is more than the supported max container capability in the cluster. Killing the Job. reduceResourceRequest: <memory:8192, vCores:1> maxContainerCapability:<memory:5413, vCores:4>`

Regards